# retrofit okhttpclient with CertificatePinner

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Retrofit 2.0.0-beta3 with OkHttp 3.0.0-RC1 and facing below trivial issue. The HTTPS server I am connecting to works fine with I use CertificatePinner and OkHttp call but does not work with Retrofit call even though I am setting the same client in Retrofit instance

```
String hostname = "hostname";
CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
        .add(hostname, "sha1/rNKiM/IsTzTMJ09jpMtPq4qP+Q8=")
        .add(hostname, "sha1/hL8+j9RH89wlAW7eNDSS1ZlZ8Z8=")
        .build();
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().certificatePinner(certificatePinner).build();

// This call works
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().certificatePinner(certificatePinner).build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("https://" + hostname + "/api/me")
    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer token")
    .build();
okhttp3.Call call = client.newCall(request);
//execute call returns 200 with response

// This is not working and throwing SSL Connection Error
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://" + hostname)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .client(client)
        .build();
```

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"?

Comment: @Robert it is fixed now, I found a bug in execution order. I have put my answer below

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in app due to which the client was created before below code:

```
ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplication());
```

The order is fixed now and the code works fine.